# Sqlite File Upload in WebView Without filechooser

Tags: android, file-upload, webview

May be like Duplicate, but I cant find most suitable answer for me. Many examples have explain about img files. like this, [Android Java Upload File via WebView without FileChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425400/android-java-upload-file-via-webview-without-filechooser) I want to upload .db file into my web server from my android application using Webview.  but I cant understand what I want to do. Is that possible (upload .db file)? And if yes, what I want to do? Im new for android.

Comment: How does the webview know the path to your file?

Comment: You can upload any file you want with code that can upload a file.

Comment: And why should your webview do the upload?